# Best way to split arduino files

Tags: arduino, mqtt, iot

I´m looking for the best way to split arduino files, the code that I had pasted below it just for compiled test is only to understand how this works. In this example I try to split my MQTT code.

This the enviroment:

**main.ino file:**

```cpp
        #include "file.h"
        //and more libraries
        void setup() {
          // put your setup code here, to run once:
          Serial.begin(115200);
          setup_mqtt(); //declared in file.h
        }
       
        // a lot of code here
    
        void loop() {
          // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
            if (!client.connected()) {
            reconnect(); //declared in file.h
            mqtt_mensaje(); //declared in file.h
          }
        }
```

**file.h file:**

```cpp
    void setup_mqtt();
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
    void reconnect();
    void mqtt_mensaje();
```

**file.cpp file**

```cpp
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <WiFiClient.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h>
    #define LED_BUILTIN 4   
    const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.18";
    // Connectión WiFi +  Broker
    WiFiClient espClient;
    PubSubClient client(espClient);
    
    // Function MQTT ------------------------
    void reconnect() {
     //code
    }
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
      //code
      reconnect();
    }
    
    void mqtt_mensaje() {
    //code PUB message
    }
    //End Functions MQTT-----------------------

    void setup_mqtt(){
      
      pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);      
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    
      // Configuración MQTT
      client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
      client.setCallback(callback);
    }
```

When I run this code in my Arduino IDE I get :

**/Users/charlysan/Projects/works/arduino/main/main.ino: In function 'void loop()':
main:9:10: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope
if (!client.connected()) {
^**

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best way to split C++ code. An answer to that would always be opinionated.

Regarding your error message add

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>

extern PubSubClient client;
```

to get rid of that error message you could declare it as extern so the compiler knows it is instanciated somewhere else.
Add

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>

extern PubSubClient client;
```

to your .ino.

I personally don't see a reason why you should instanciate that in another file though.